# Avro and Kafka by making use of SchemaBuilder

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I went through the tutorial from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-apache-avro). They mention there are two ways to create a schema.

- By writing the json representation and adding the maven plugin to produce the class
- By using the `SchemaBuilder`, which they also mention is a better choice.

Unfortunately in the git example I only see the json way.

Lets say I have this Avro schema:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"TestFile",
  "namespace":"com.example.kafka.data.ingestion.model",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"date",
      "type":"long"
    },
    {
      "name":"counter",
      "type":"int"
    },
    {
      "name":"mc",
      "type":"string"
    }
  ]
}
```

By adding this plugin in my pom file:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
   <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>schemas</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>schema</goal>
            <goal>protocol</goal>
            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

and building with generate-sources a `TestFile.java` is created to the destination I said. 
Then for sending to a kafka topic I can do the following:

```
TestFile test = TestFile.newBuilder()
                                            .setDate(102928374747)
                                            .setCounter(2)
                                            .setMc("Some string")
                                            .build();
kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, test);
```

The equivalent of creating the schema with `SchemaBuilder` would be:

```
Schema testFileSchema = SchemaBuilder   .record("TestFile")
                                            .namespace("com.example.kafka.data.ingestion.model")
                                            .fields()
                                            .requiredLong("date")
                                            .requiredInt("counter")
                                            .requiredString("mc")
                                            .endRecord();
```

But how can I now generate the POJO and send my `TestFile` data to my kafka topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have access to a `TestFile` object since the Schema is made at runtime, not pre-compiled. If you want to keep that POJO, then you would need a constructor for `public TestFile(GenericRecord avroRecord)`

You'll need to create a `GenericRecord` using that `Schema` object, same as if you were parsing it from a String or a file.

For example,

```
Schema schema = SchemaBuilder.record("TestFile")
            .namespace("com.example.kafka.data.ingestion.model")
            .fields()
            .requiredLong("date")
            .requiredInt("counter")
            .requiredString("mc")
            .endRecord();

GenericRecord entry1 = new GenericData.Record(schema);
entry1.put("date", 1L);
entry1.put("counter", 2);
entry1.put("mc", "3");

// producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, entry1);
```

A full Kafka example is [available from Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#serializer)

If you put don't include a required field, it'll throw an error, and the values of the types are not checked (I could put `"counter", "2"`, and it would send a string value (this seems to be a bug to me). Basically, `GenericRecord == HashMap<String, Object>` with the added benefit of reqiured/nullable fields.

And you will need to configure an Avro serializer, such as Confluent's, which requires running their Schema Registry, or a version like [Cloudera shows](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2018/07/robust-message-serialization-in-apache-kafka-using-apache-avro-part-1/)

Otherwise, you need to convert the Avro object into a `byte[]` (as shown in your linkand just use the `ByteArraySerializer`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Baeldung tutorial:

> Later we can apply the toString method to get the JSON structure of
> Schema.

So for example using this code inside a main class you can print the two schemas definition to the console output.

You can then save the resulting json representations to .avsc file and generate pojos as before.

```
    Schema clientIdentifier = SchemaBuilder.record("ClientIdentifier")
            .namespace("com.baeldung.avro")
            .fields().requiredString("hostName").requiredString("ipAddress")
            .endRecord();
    System.out.println(clientIdentifier.toString());

    Schema avroHttpRequest = SchemaBuilder.record("AvroHttpRequest")
            .namespace("com.baeldung.avro")
            .fields().requiredLong("requestTime")
            .name("clientIdentifier")
            .type(clientIdentifier)
            .noDefault()
            .name("employeeNames")
            .type()
            .array()
            .items()
            .stringType()
            .arrayDefault(new ArrayList<>())
            .name("active")
            .type()
            .enumeration("Active")
            .symbols("YES","NO")
            .noDefault()
            .endRecord();
    System.out.println(avroHttpRequest.toString());
```

There is a third way to generate Avro schemas that is using [Avro IDL](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.2/idl.html)